# Сижу уже час и не могу понять как написать код на Python

Tags: python

1 ) напишите функцию slice_less,

на вход принимает:

1. первый аргумент “my_list” - список из целых чисел
2. второй аргумент “lesser” - целое число

выводит:

отсортированный от большего к меньшему список my_list, где все значения больше чем lesser

2 ) напишите функцию biggest_value,

на вход принимает:

1. первый аргумент “my_list” - список из целых чисел

выводит:

целое число максимально возможное что может получиться
пример :

на вход  [22, 1, 62, 33]

на выход 6233221

```
values = input('Введите числа через запятую: ')
ints_as_strings = values.split(',')
ints = map(int, ints_as_strings)
lst = list(ints)
tup = tuple(lst)
print('Список:', lst)
```

вот пробовал так но это походу не правильно

Comment: Добрый день, на этом сайте принято помогать с задачами, а не решать за кого-то либо. Поэтому, пожалуйста, добавьте вашу попытку решить задачу (в виде кода в вопросе), иначе вопрос может быть закрыт. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def slice_less(my_list, lesser): 
    '''
    Фильтруем список по числам, которые больше lesser
    Сортируем от 1 до n и потом с помощью [::-1] делаем обратный порядок
    '''
    return sorted(filter(lambda x: x > lesser, my_list))[::-1]


def biggest_value(my_list):
    '''
    Сортируем массив от большего к меньшему.
    Соединяем элементы списка и получаем самое большое "число"
    '''
    return ''.join(map(str, sorted(my_list)[::-1]))
```

P.S. Если все же автору надо была функция, которая находит масимальное число, составляя числа из списка, то:

```
def biggest_value(my_list):
    return ''.join(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: str(x)[0])[::-1])

biggest_value([22, 9, 62, 33])        # 9623322
biggest_value([22, 901, 920, 62, 33]) # 920901623322
```

Comment: Не надо именовать лямбды.

Comment: Сейчас доведется. Лямбда — это анонимная функция, т.е. без имени. И лучше будет так: лямбда — без имени, а обычная функция — с именем, как оно того предпологает ;)

Comment: 2 функция точно не рабочая. Введите 9 место 1 и получите неправильный ответ

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, вторая функция работает как пример у автора, хоть и описание немного отличается. Она должна составить максимальное число из тех чисел, которые есть, а не из цифр. Если Вы об этом.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, вполне логично.

Comment: максимальное число из  [22, 9, 62, 33] не будет 6233229, а будет 9623322. Или я не правильно понял задание?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, неправильно поняли. Я же говорю, у атвора вопроса описание второй функции не совсем совпадает с примером :) Там не надо делить число на цифры. Я сделал по примеру.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, я как понял оно должно на выходе их от большего к меньшему сложить

Comment: @entithat спасибо больше)